# Highchart- X-axis Irregular Time interval pointWidth

Tags: highcharts

I am facing an issue with x-axis coordinates ticks and pointWidth with below data as x-axis is not following coordinates.

```
var temperatures = [
[Date.UTC(2016, 3, 1, 0 , 0), 0],
[Date.UTC(2016, 3, 1, 15, 0), 40],
[Date.UTC(2016, 3, 1, 15, 45), 30],
[Date.UTC(2016, 3, 1, 16, 20), 0],
```

];

OR Here is the same data in integer form

```
data: [
            [1459490400000, 0],
            [1459522800000, 40],
            [1459525500000, 30],
            [1459527600000, 0]
        ]
```

Issue is that there must not be any gap between these to points as shown in below attachment.
[Click here to check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SurenderK/19gk0f7x/)

[image: Below is screenshot of issue]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that your data is irregular. Highcharts, by default calculates minimum distance between columns, then calculates column width and renders all points with a given width. If you change all `0` values to something else, then you will see that two **closest** points are rendered without any gap between them. You can achieve what you want to using `ordinal` xAxis. But this `ordinal` feature is part only of the Highstock, see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/19gk0f7x/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using pointWidth, set the [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.pointRange) parameter and then [groupPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.groupPadding) and [pointPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.pointPadding) as 0.